# Is a Batch file what I need?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a script that will set the file associations for mostly MS Office files and a few other files extensions to the local applications (they would currently be through citrix). I am planning on using a simple Batch file.

However I would like it to be able to detect whether the filetype is valid and create it if not using ftype. I would also like it to be able to detect/differentiate between whether the user has MS Office 2003 or MS Office 2007 and associate accordingly.

My question is, will a Batch file be able to do all this, or am I better off using something else like a vb script (taking into account I know NO vb, although I'm pretty novice with Batch files too)??

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: I should have bee clearer that this is in a locked down environment, so no direct registry editoring can be done, and it will need to be available to users, from a shared drive or something similiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file alone can't detect if the file association is correct, but you could just fire the batch file everytime anyway, forcing the file association to be correct. It'll just overwrite what's already there.

Just create the proper associations yourself, then run Regedit and export a .reg file containing the association keys, and use a batch file that runs regedit to import the keys. Probably /import or somesuch - I rarely use Windows anymore!

Here's a page that explains it: 
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php

Comment: I would love to be able to do this, but we work in an environment where the user's don't have that kind of access, and we don't the the permissions to pop it out to them!
You are right about just forcing the associations each time, but this would mean the need for 2 seperate scripts depending on the version of MS office installed.

Comment: If there a specific file or filename you can look for, then a single batch file would do it - you can test for the existence of a file from the batch, and execute something different based on that.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the level to which, or how, the environment is locked down. You can execute scripts as a different user in many cases. If Office is loaded, why aren't the correct file associations already present?

Comment: Checking for a file is what I need! The user will either have Office 2003 loaded or Office 2007, so if I can check each file path and then create the association bassed on the path that is valid that would be perfect!
The associations get re directed by Citrix, currently when we take people off this and so they use the local office by default it doesn't update the associations, we set them manually (is in open with on each file) which you can imgaine is tedious, so I was hoping I can chuck it all into the Batch and have it as a one click!

Comment: That's just -  if exist 'c:\somefile' goto :somelabel

Comment: Shows how much I know about batch files! Thanks for your help on this Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell scripts. You get the power of .NET, a very good scripting language and you can effectively do anything you can with vbscripts and bat files. You also have a very vibrant community. And Powershell makes operating with registry so easy and intuitive that you will not know the difference between operating on files and operating on registry items

Comment: Again would love to be able to do this, should have mentioned that the environment is fairly locked down, so direct Registry editoring is out, and install new software is out as well.

Comment: Which OS? Powershell is the standard in more recent server and desktop OSs.

Comment: Old XP builds as well as newer Win7 ones, I'll have a look into it